# Android InstantApp: Can one InstantApp have multiple base modules?

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

Looking at InstantApp documentation and gradle/manifest setup, but not sure if we can have one InstantApp with 2 base modules?

**Main app**

- app module (base module 1)
- data module (base module 2)
- feature module 1
- feature module 2
- feature module 3
- feature module 4

**Instant app**

- app module (base module 1)
- data module (base module 2)
- feature module 1
- feature module 2

Comment: Found Google sample code that helps understand these dynamic modules little more. https://github.com/android/app-bundle-samples

Answer (score 0):

It can only have one base module (there's no single application, which would have more than one entry point), but I think one can force features to be installed along with it. At least with DFM it's alike this, therefore it might behave similar. And if not, just package a single base module.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. The second base module would just turn into a feature module. Our data module is created to easily unit tests w/o any Android dependencies.

Comment: It really depends... when the data is essential for the application to run, this should go into the base module - when it is not essential, it can be delivered as a feature module.